# How to pass data between controllers using Storyboard in Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

**How to pass data between controller using UIStoryboard in swift 3.0 ?**

I created **login (LoginViewController)** and **main (ViewController**) page where apps keep active if user did not logout.

So far it work.

And I have these JSON value **"login"** that need to be passed from **LoginViewController** into **ViewController**

Some of people suggest to use **perform and prepare segue**.

It work but the value can only be display if it sent from LoginViewController.

ViewController did not hold the data when the page ViewController is active (when i rebuild/clean the apps).

My goal is to keep the "login" data in ViewController when page is active and clear "login" data when the page logout.

**LoginViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var _loginLbl: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var _pwLbl: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var login_button: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var outputLbl: UILabel!

    var login: String!
    var pw: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {super.viewDidLoad()}

    @IBAction func loginData(_ sender: Any) {
        login = _loginLbl.text
        pw    = _pwLbl.text

            let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/login.php")
            let session = URLSession.shared

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"

            let LoginDataToPost = "login=\(login!)&pw=\(pw!)"
            request.httpBody = LoginDataToPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
                (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    return
                }
                else {
                    do {
                        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: String]
                        {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async
                            {
                                let message = Int(json["message"]!)
                                let login   = json["login"]

                                if(message == 1) {
                                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
                                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
                                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

                                    let myViewController:ViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
                                    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                                    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = myViewController
                                    appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

                                    self.outputLbl.text = login;

                                    return
                                }
                                else { }
                            }  
                        }  
                        else { }
                    } catch let jsonParse {}
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var loginLbl: UILabel!
    var login: String!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard

         if(preferences.object(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn") != nil){
            loginLbl.text = login
         }
         else {

         }
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let isUserLoggedIn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
        if(!isUserLoggedIn){
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginview", sender: self)
        }
    }
    @IBAction func logoutData(_ sender: Any) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
        let loginViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginview") as! LoginViewController
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = loginViewController
        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

}
```

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Just store your response as model class or dictionary, and that model class or dictionary into userdefault, and check it at every didlaunchwithfinish that if your app have data or not in userdefault, if have load it.

Comment: What data you want to save?

Comment: I want to save "login" data into ViewController.

Comment: @RahulPatel on which page should i set that data ?

Comment: @AlotJai in LoginViewController under

  if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: String]
                        { }

I am thinking that you got some user's data based on particular user login.

Comment: @alotjai if you are storing the data in userdefaults you can access it in  whole domain then what problem you are facing right now ?

Comment: Right now i'm having a problem the keep/hold the "login" data when the apps restarted

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can store the value in NSUserDefaults in LoginViewController. Like below :

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(login, forKey: "loginJSONValue")
```

And get the value in ViewController like this (I assume that the value is String):

```
textField1.text = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "loginJSONValue") as? String
```

**LoginViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var _loginLbl: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var _pwLbl: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var login_button: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var outputLbl: UILabel!

    var login: String!
    var pw: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {super.viewDidLoad()}

    @IBAction func loginData(_ sender: Any) {
        login = _loginLbl.text
        pw    = _pwLbl.text

            let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/login.php")
            let session = URLSession.shared

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"

            let LoginDataToPost = "login=\(login!)&pw=\(pw!)"
            request.httpBody = LoginDataToPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
                (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    return
                }
                else {
                    do {
                        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: String]
                        {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async
                            {
                                let message = Int(json["message"]!)
                                let login   = json["login"]

                                if(message == 1) {
                                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
                                    UserDefaults.standard.set(login, forKey: "loginJSONValue")
                                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
                                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

                                    let myViewController:ViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
                                    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                                    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = myViewController
                                    appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

                                    self.outputLbl.text = login;

                                    return
                                }
                                else { }
                            }  
                        }  
                        else { }
                    } catch let jsonParse {}
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var loginLbl: UILabel!
    var login: String!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard

         if(preferences.object(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn") != nil){

// let isUserLoggedIn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
            let isUserLoggedIn = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn") as Bool
    // your login data is below. do what you want to do
                login = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "loginJSONValue") as String
                if(!isUserLoggedIn){
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginview", sender: self)
                }
            loginLbl.text = login
         }
         else {

         }
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        }

        @IBAction func logoutData(_ sender: Any) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
// After logging out, you can set empty to login data.
UserDefaults.standard.set("", forKey: "loginJSONValue");
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
            let loginViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginview") as! LoginViewController
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = loginViewController
            appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback . I'll try it first . . :)

Comment: I'm not sure why in ViewController cannot save the value from LoginViewController . .

Comment: In your code, it saves "isUserLoggedIn" value to UserDefaults. You are not saving the "login" variable to UserDefaults. It is normal that your ViewController can not read the "login" value. And also i can't see the line that you trying to get "login" value from UserDefaults. You read "isUserLoggedIn" and you are doing it right. Try my code, it will work. I am using it at my applications.

Comment: I'm still confuse . .Can you update my code above on your answer ? thanks

Comment: Updated, check it.

Comment: I've updated it again. I realized that you use your login variable at viewDidLoad but getting the value from UserDefaults at viewDidAppear. ViewDidAppear is working after viewDidLoad. That was one of your problems. The code above should work.

Comment: i see. let me try it first, i'll let you know later .thanks btw :D

Comment: Yess . it works :) . . Thank you so much . . god bless you . .

Comment: @AlotJai If this is working for you then this is exactly the same whatever I have mentioned you.

Answer (score -1):

You need to call Login service again and pass the data when application is restarted. or you can stored data in UserDefault and reuse it.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(login, forKey: "loginResponse")
```

You can pass data from one controller to another controller as below:

```
  let myViewController:ViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
var loginResponse = UserDefaults.standard.get(forKey:"loginResponse")
myViewController.your_object = loginResponse
```

Comment: I already add UserDefaults in ViewController didLoad method. but it didnt work . i dont know why. btw . thanks for the feedback ..

Comment: can you show me a which code you write for store and retried login data? so i can help you more.

Comment: in LoginViewController.swift . . in if statement block where if (message == 1)

Comment: it's in the if statement ("if message == 1") that i store the data :)